# Not able to loop a sequence of animation using $.Velocity.RunSequence

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, velocity.js

I am trying to loop a sequence of animation using Velocity UI library but the sequence runs once successfully and then stops.

I tried adding {loop: "true"} after the animationSequence, but it didn't work. Please help.

Below is the script:

```
var animationSequence = [
{ 
  e: $(".custom-set-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 3500 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-2 .text-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-2 .text-2"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-2 .text-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 3500 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-2 .text-2"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-3 .text-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-3 .text-2"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-3 .text-1"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 3500 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-3 .text-2"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-4"), 
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-4"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 3500 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-5"),
  p: { opacity: 1 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000 } 
}, { 
  e: $(".custom-set-5"), 
  p: { opacity: 0 }, 
  o: { duration: 1000, delay: 3500 } 
}];

$.Velocity.RunSequence(animationSequence, {loop: "true"});
```